# Style.Display = "None" Not working in Google Apps Script HTML Service

Tags: javascript, dom, google-apps-script

I've got a fairly simple javascript function running in my HTML service template that is supposed to set the display of a div to "none."  However, whenever I include the following line:

```
document.getElementById("timesheet").style.display = "none";
```

I get an error in my browser: "Cannot call method 'f___' of undefined."  When I take it out, no errors.

Can someone please tell me if I'm missing something?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with that line of code.. Can you include anymore info? Are you sure that the `<div>` you're trying to point to has `id="timesheet"`?

Comment: Either there is no element with the id `timesheet`, or you have encountered a bug.

Comment: Since this is a Google Apps Script template, it also gets processed first. You need to make sure you are calling the JavaScript from an appropriate place. You can't do this in an element's "onClick" event directly for instance. Need more code/context here.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a decade old, but Google Apps Script doesn't know what "document" is by default. Debugging the function that contains this line of code will verify that

AFAIK (at least for editing sidebars), I don't think there's a direct way to edit the DOM like you can in a typical webpage

The best you can do I think is to use the functions provided [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#addmetatagname,-content)

Answer (score -1):

Just use jQuery instead.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#whateverYouAreClickingIDHere").click(function () {
      $("#timesheet").css('display','none');
    });
});
</script>
```